# How instance attributes are passed to the decorator inner function?

Tags: python, python-decorators, nested-function

I recently studied how decorators work in python, and found an example which integrates decorators with nested functions.
The code is here :

```
def integer_check(method):
    def inner(ref):
        if not isinstance(ref._val1, int) or not isinstance(ref._val2, int):
            raise TypeError('val1 and val2 must be integers')
        else:
            return method(ref)
    return inner


class NumericalOps(object):
    def __init__(self, val1, val2):
        self._val1 = val1
        self._val2 = val2

    @integer_check
    def multiply_together(self):
        return self._val1 * self._val2

    def power(self, exponent):
        return self.multiply_together() ** exponent

y = NumericalOps(1, 2)

print(y.multiply_together())
print(y.power(3))
```

My question is how the inner function argument("ref") accesses the instance attributes (ref._val1 and ref._val2)?
It seems like ref equals the instance but i have no idea how it happenes.

Answer (score 0):

well one explanation I found some time ago about the `self` argument was that this:

```py
y.multiply_together()
```

is roughly the same as

```py
NumericalOps.multiply_together(y)
```

So now that you use that decorator it returns the function `inner` which requires the `ref` argument so I see that roughly happen like this (on a lower level):

```py
NumericalOps.inner(y)
```

Because `inner` "substitutes" `multiply_together` while also adding the extra functionality

Answer (score 0):

Let's first recall how a decorator works:

Decorating the method `multiply_together` with the decorator `@integer_check` is equivalent to adding the line: `multiply_together = integer_check(multiply_together)`, and by the definition of `multiply_together`, this is equivalent to `multiply_together = inner`.

Now, when you call the method `multiply_together`, since this is an instance method, Python implicitly adds the class instance used to invoke the method as its first (an only, in this case) argument. But `multiply_togethet` is, actually,`inner`, so, in fact, `inner` is invoked with the class instance as an argument. This instance is mapped to the parameter `ref`, and through this parameter the function gets access to the required instance attributes.

Comment: thanks  you for complete answer

Answer (score 0):

`inner` *replaces* the original function as the value of the class attribute.

```
@integer_check
def multiply_together(self):
    return self._val1 * self._val2

# def multiply_together(self):
#     ...
#
# multiply_together = integer_check(multiply_together)
```

first defines a function and binds it to the name `multiply_together`. That function is then passed as the argument to `integer_check`, and then the return value of `integer_check` is bound to the name `multiply_together`. The original function is now only refernced by the name `ref` that is local to `inner`/`multiply_together`.

The definition of `inner` implies that `integer_check` can *only* be applied to functions whose first argument will have attributes named `_val1` and `_val2`.